# thingamajig, doohickey, whatchamacallit, thingamabob &c

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What might be used in Latin for such place holders? The word ‘gadget’ apparently was first used in this sense viz. a widely agreed upon form used to replace a word temporarily forgotten. I suppose ‘nomen nescio’ is a possibility and for a person Numerius Negidius or Aulus Agerius but these are used specifically in legal contexts as the Wikipedia article explains, for which see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerius_Negidius and https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=Numerius+Negidius. Perhaps there is a term in Renaissance literature but so far I have not come across it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess I'd just go with *nescio quid*. It's a common enough idiom, although I'm sure there are many other more comical ways to say thingamabob.

Comment: Thanks, Figulus. A good start!

Comment: [This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4996/79) seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. Very relevant!